# Reference element property within another property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to access properties (`fieldType`, `value`) within an dynamic property (`:class`)

```
<div fieldType="favoriteSports" 
     @click="update_favorite_sports" 
     value="Soccer"
     :class="{selected: sportsForm[fieldType].indexOf(value) != -1 }">
     Soccer
</div>
```

This logs the following error:

```
Property or method "fieldType" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
```

I suppose it is expecting fieldType to be a data property.

How can this be achieved, or is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: Is this for a dynamically generated field system? is there any reason you can't use `:class="{selected: sportsForm['favoriteSports'].indexOf('Soccer') != -1 }"`?

Comment: @JustinMacArthur Yes I am looking for a solution to abstract this into a v-for. As you can imagine there will be >20 sports, dynamically inserted

Comment: ok and what variable are you using to fill `fieldType` and `value` because you should be able to pass it into the class selector. I'll write up an answer showcasing how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `v-for` to fill values exposes the entire object to the template syntax

I'm assuming your object system but it's universal to different structures.

```
<div
    v-for="sport in sports"
    :fieldType="sport.type"
    @click="update_favorite_sports(sport)" 
    :value="sport.name"
    :class="{selected: sportsForm[sport.type].indexOf(sport.name) != -1 }"
>
    Soccer
</div>
```

Though honestly you no longer need the `value` and `fieldType` properties unless you're referencing them somewhere.

That will allow you to use

```
methods: {
    update_favorite_sports (sport) {
        // Whatever your code is guessing something like
        let index = this.sportsForm[sport.type].indexOf(sport.name)
        if(index >= 0) {
            this.sportsForm[sport.type].splice(index, 1)
            return
        }
        this.sportsForm[sport.type].push(sport.name)
    }
}
```

So that the div acts like a radio select.