# access other properties of the same element by another property in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to access other properties of the same element by another property in Vue.js ?

**example**:

instead of writing:

```html
<kpi title="some_kpi" v-if="displayed_kpi==='some_kpi'"></kpi>
```

do something like this:

```html
<kpi title="some_kpi" v-if="displayed_kpi===title"></kpi>
```

which means that I want to access the value of the title inside the v-if of the same tag. (Obviously this doesn't work like this) Is there a way ?

Comment: `title` is a variable that will be inside `data`'s component?

Comment: @null yes, title is available inside kpi component as props

Comment: You already know the value of `title` at the same level as the `v-if`, regardless of whether `title` is dynamic or not. Just use the same value in both `title` and `v-if`.

Comment: That's obviously how it is done. As I said I was wondering if there was a cooler way to do it in vue.js, looks like there isn't, so conventional solution it is.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944054/reference-element-property-within-another-property

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You can access the attributes of an element by the [$refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) variable. This is a great way to get information from nested components, since you have access to the `children` attribute of the element. ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676654/vue-access-nested-childs-using-ref))

However, adding the `ref` attribute will not work for your example with the `v-if` because when `v-if` is false it removes the entire element.

Plus, there would be issues of synchronization with the $refs variable and the creation of the element. Here is more on [lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html)).

```html
<button @click="$event => $forceUpdate()">update me</button>
<kpi ref="MyKpi" title="some_kpi">{{ $refs.MyKpi?.title }}</kpi>
```

This show how on render `$refs.MyKpi` does not exist because the element has not been rendered. but when you force the DOM to update. you can see that we do have access to the attributes in the kpi element.

The `$refs` variable gives you flexibility for more complex operations on attributes of elements.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question but it is a workaround. In my case its not that important, I was mostly wondering if the feature existed in vue. Thank you though

Comment: Have you heard of [props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) and and the [$emit](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) features. Those might be what you are looking for.

Comment: yes i'm familiar with props and emit, but no these are not what i'm looking for

Comment: I update my answer. the $refs feature is pretty cool.

Comment: this requires the addition of a unique "MyKpi", which somewhat defeats the original purpose: to avoid adding a value, but to reuse "some_kpi".

Comment: Perhaps a better solution is to use `v-for` (although not quite for purpose).